# Why will my vs-code snippet not work when the format has been met?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

i am trying to get the snippet to do this

```
recipes.addShaped("name", output,
[
[input,input,input],
[input,input,input],
[input,input,input]
]);
```

the code i am trying to use is this

```
"Add a shaped": {
    "prefix": ["rec", "add"],
    "body": ["
recipes.addShaped("${1:name}", ${2:output},
[
[${3:input},${4:input},${5:input}],
[${6:input},${7:input},${8:input}],
[${9:input},${10:input},${11:input}]
]);

"],
    "description": "Add a shaped recipe."
  }
```

any help would be appreciated.
dan

Comment: Each line of the body has to be within quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Add a shaped": {
  "prefix": ["rec", "add"],
  "body": [
    "recipes.addShaped(\"${1:name}\", ${2:output},",
    "[",
    "[${3:input},${4:input},${5:input}],",
    "[${6:input},${7:input},${8:input}],",
    "[${9:input},${10:input},${11:input}]",
    "]);"
  ],
  "description": "Add a shaped recipe."
},
```

All lines of the body have to be separately quoted and the qoutes within a line have to be escaped.

And the result will appear flush left with your current indentation without having to put the body far left like you had it.  Just indent the snippet normally to set the left point.  Any indentation from there will indent the result.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it.